# SharePoint timer job add list items, but does not trigger the associated workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-timer-job

I have a list called "Sessions", The list has a workflow which runs for item creation, modification. The workflow triggers when i add items using a web part as well as manually . I have developed a timer job which runs daily, which adds items to "Sessions" list.  **When timer job add items to the list, workflow does not trigger.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating or editing a list item using the API will not trigger workflows. You have to use the [`SPWorkflowManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager.aspx) class to trigger it yourself. Every instance of `SPSite` has a property of just that type, which is what you should use.

You could code it like this:

```
SPSite site = foo; // Actually get your instance of SPSite by whatever is
                   // your favorite way to do so.

site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(
        item,
        association,
        association.AssociationData,
        isAutoStart);
```

Where `item` is the SPListItem which you have created/edited, `association` is the instance of [`SPWorkflowAssociation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociation.aspx) that correlates the list to the actual workflow, and `isAutoStart` is a `boolean` variable telling the workflow manager whether the workflow trigger should behave as something that was started automatically (in your case, `true`).

Comment: Have you got a source for the statement, creating or editing a  list item using the API will not trigger workflows ?

I've seen other posts that say they do but require, site.WorkflowManager.Dispose().

Comment: Empirical evidence. Try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that.

I think what you meant to say was 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947284
http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start.aspx

You're right, other chap was well wrong. :-)

Comment: I work mostly with SharePoint Online, where you don't have access to those settings. I was speaking mostly from experience, but it is good to know that with an in-premises installation workflows can be triggered normally without the need for extra coding. Thanks for that :)