# Workflow not working when Item is added by TimerJob in SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

> Hi,
>
> I've created a Timer Job which will add an item to a list every 10
>   minutes. I've also configured a workflow to send one email as soon
>   item is added. This workflow is working fine if I'm adding entry
>   manually. If entry is added by TimerJob then workflow isn't working.
>   Can anyone guide me?

Code of same is:

```
  SPWorkflowAssociation wrkFl = timerJobList.WorkflowAssociations[new Guid("366024bf-1605-43a0-b7dd-03a54623ee79")];
site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(newItem, wrkFl, wrkFl.AssociationData, true);
                newItem.Update();
```

> Regards, Vikrant

Answer (score 0):

Item creation by timer job doesn't start workflow. You have to start it manually using

```
WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow
```

More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810185/sharepoint-timer-job-add-list-items-but-does-not-trigger-the-associated-workflo)

Comment: I've done same. Please check the updated question for the code.